# MAMP + Dropbox - Fixing 403 Errors

Tags: macos, apache, permissions, mamp, http-status-code-403

I have been struggling for over a week now to get [Bitnami MAMP](http://bitnami.com/stack/mamp) working on my OSX Lion MacBook Air. I want to set up a local webserver for testing, and I want my sites in my Dropbox folder so I can also work on projects on my other Windows PC.

Here's where I am so far... hopefully you can see what I am doing wrong.

httpd.conf:

```
#
# This is the main Apache HTTP server configuration file.  It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/> for detailed information.
# In particular, see 
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/directives.html>
# for a discussion of each configuration directive.
#
# Do NOT simply read the instructions in here without understanding
# what they do.  They're here only as hints or reminders.  If you are unsure
# consult the online docs. You have been warned.  
#
# Configuration and logfile names: If the filenames you specify for many
# of the server's control files begin with "/" (or "drive:/" for Win32), the
# server will use that explicit path.  If the filenames do *not* begin
# with "/", the value of ServerRoot is prepended -- so "logs/access_log"
# with ServerRoot set to "/usr/local/apache2" will be interpreted by the
# server as "/usr/local/apache2/logs/access_log", whereas "/logs/access_log" 
# will be interpreted as '/logs/access_log'.

#
# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.
#
# Do not add a slash at the end of the directory path.  If you point
# ServerRoot at a non-local disk, be sure to specify a local disk on the
# Mutex directive, if file-based mutexes are used.  If you wish to share the
# same ServerRoot for multiple httpd daemons, you will need to change at
# least PidFile.
#
ServerRoot "/Applications/MampStack.app/Contents/Resources/app/apache2"

#
# Mutex: Allows you to set the mutex mechanism and mutex file directory
# for individual mutexes, or change the global defaults
#
# Uncomment and change the directory if mutexes are file-based and the default
# mutex file directory is not on a local disk or is not appropriate for some
# other reason.
#
# Mutex default:logs

#
# Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
# ports, instead of the default. See also the <VirtualHost>
# directive.
#
# Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to 
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
#
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 8080

#
# Dynamic Shared Object (DSO) Support
#
# To be able to use the functionality of a module which was built as a DSO you
# have to place corresponding `LoadModule' lines at this location so the
# directives contained in it are actually available _before_ they are used.
# Statically compiled modules (those listed by `httpd -l') do not need
# to be loaded here.
#
# Example:
# LoadModule foo_module modules/mod_foo.so
#
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
#LoadModule authn_dbm_module modules/mod_authn_dbm.so
#LoadModule authn_anon_module modules/mod_authn_anon.so
#LoadModule authn_dbd_module modules/mod_authn_dbd.so
#LoadModule authn_socache_module modules/mod_authn_socache.so
LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
#LoadModule authz_dbm_module modules/mod_authz_dbm.so
#LoadModule authz_owner_module modules/mod_authz_owner.so
#LoadModule authz_dbd_module modules/mod_authz_dbd.so
LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
#LoadModule authnz_ldap_module modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
LoadModule access_compat_module modules/mod_access_compat.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
#LoadModule auth_form_module modules/mod_auth_form.so
#LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
#LoadModule allowmethods_module modules/mod_allowmethods.so
#LoadModule file_cache_module modules/mod_file_cache.so
#LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
#LoadModule cache_disk_module modules/mod_cache_disk.so
LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so
#LoadModule socache_dbm_module modules/mod_socache_dbm.so
#LoadModule socache_memcache_module modules/mod_socache_memcache.so
#LoadModule dbd_module modules/mod_dbd.so
#LoadModule dumpio_module modules/mod_dumpio.so
#LoadModule buffer_module modules/mod_buffer.so
#LoadModule ratelimit_module modules/mod_ratelimit.so
LoadModule reqtimeout_module modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
#LoadModule ext_filter_module modules/mod_ext_filter.so
#LoadModule request_module modules/mod_request.so
#LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
#LoadModule substitute_module modules/mod_substitute.so
#LoadModule sed_module modules/mod_sed.so
#LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
#LoadModule ldap_module modules/mod_ldap.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
#LoadModule log_debug_module modules/mod_log_debug.so
#LoadModule logio_module modules/mod_logio.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
#LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
#LoadModule unique_id_module modules/mod_unique_id.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
#LoadModule remoteip_module modules/mod_remoteip.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module modules/mod_proxy_fcgi.so
LoadModule proxy_scgi_module modules/mod_proxy_scgi.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
LoadModule proxy_express_module modules/mod_proxy_express.so
#LoadModule session_module modules/mod_session.so
#LoadModule session_cookie_module modules/mod_session_cookie.so
#LoadModule session_dbd_module modules/mod_session_dbd.so
LoadModule slotmem_shm_module modules/mod_slotmem_shm.so
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
LoadModule lbmethod_byrequests_module modules/mod_lbmethod_byrequests.so
LoadModule lbmethod_bytraffic_module modules/mod_lbmethod_bytraffic.so
LoadModule lbmethod_bybusyness_module modules/mod_lbmethod_bybusyness.so
#LoadModule lbmethod_heartbeat_module modules/mod_lbmethod_heartbeat.so
LoadModule unixd_module modules/mod_unixd.so
#LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
#LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
#LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
#LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
#LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
#LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
#LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so
#LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule php5_module        modules/libphp5.so

<IfModule unixd_module>
#
# If you wish httpd to run as a different user or group, you must run
# httpd as root initially and it will switch.  
#
# User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
# It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
# running httpd, as with most system services.
#
User daemon
Group daemon

</IfModule>

# 'Main' server configuration
#
# The directives in this section set up the values used by the 'main'
# server, which responds to any requests that aren't handled by a
# <VirtualHost> definition.  These values also provide defaults for
# any <VirtualHost> containers you may define later in the file.
#
# All of these directives may appear inside <VirtualHost> containers,
# in which case these default settings will be overridden for the
# virtual host being defined.
#

#
# ServerAdmin: Your address, where problems with the server should be
# e-mailed.  This address appears on some server-generated pages, such
# as error documents.  e.g. admin@your-domain.com
#
ServerAdmin you@example.com

#
# ServerName gives the name and port that the server uses to identify itself.
# This can often be determined automatically, but we recommend you specify
# it explicitly to prevent problems during startup.
#
# If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.
#
ServerName localhost:8080

#
# Deny access to the entirety of your server's filesystem. You must
# explicitly permit access to web content directories in other 
# <Directory> blocks below.
#
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

#
# Note that from this point forward you must specifically allow
# particular features to be enabled - so if something's not working as
# you might expect, make sure that you have specifically enabled it
# below.
#

#
# DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
# documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
# symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
#
DocumentRoot /Users/ferg/Library/Containers/com.bitnami.mampstack/Data/app/apache2/htdocs
<Directory "/Users/ferg/Library/Containers/com.bitnami.mampstack/Data/app/apache2/htdocs">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride None

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require all granted
</Directory>

#
# DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory
# is requested.
#
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</IfModule>

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being 
# viewed by Web clients. 
#
<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

#
# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog /Users/ferg/Library/Containers/com.bitnami.mampstack/Data/app/apache2/logs/error_log

#
# LogLevel: Control the number of messages logged to the error_log.
# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
#
LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    #
    # The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
    # a CustomLog directive (see below).
    #
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      # You need to enable mod_logio.c to use %I and %O
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>

    #
    # The location and format of the access logfile (Common Logfile Format).
    # If you do not define any access logfiles within a <VirtualHost>
    # container, they will be logged here.  Contrariwise, if you *do*
    # define per-<VirtualHost> access logfiles, transactions will be
    # logged therein and *not* in this file.
    #
CustomLog /Users/ferg/Library/Containers/com.bitnami.mampstack/Data/app/apache2/logs/access_log common

    #
    # If you prefer a logfile with access, agent, and referer information
    # (Combined Logfile Format) you can use the following directive.
    #
    #CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    #
    # Redirect: Allows you to tell clients about documents that used to 
    # exist in your server's namespace, but do not anymore. The client 
    # will make a new request for the document at its new location.
    # Example:
    # Redirect permanent /foo http://www.example.com/bar

    #
    # Alias: Maps web paths into filesystem paths and is used to
    # access content that does not live under the DocumentRoot.
    # Example:
    # Alias /webpath /full/filesystem/path
    #
    # If you include a trailing / on /webpath then the server will
    # require it to be present in the URL.  You will also likely
    # need to provide a <Directory> section to allow access to
    # the filesystem path.

    #
    # ScriptAlias: This controls which directories contain server scripts. 
    # ScriptAliases are essentially the same as Aliases, except that
    # documents in the target directory are treated as applications and
    # run by the server when requested rather than as documents sent to the
    # client.  The same rules about trailing "/" apply to ScriptAlias
    # directives as to Alias.
    #
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/Applications/MampStack.app/Contents/Resources/app/apache2/cgi-bin/"

</IfModule>

<IfModule cgid_module>
    #
    # ScriptSock: On threaded servers, designate the path to the UNIX
    # socket used to communicate with the CGI daemon of mod_cgid.
    #
    #Scriptsock cgisock
</IfModule>

#
# "/Applications/MampStack.app/Contents/Resources/app/apache2/cgi-bin" should be changed to whatever your ScriptAliased
# CGI directory exists, if you have that configured.
#
<Directory "/Applications/MampStack.app/Contents/Resources/app/apache2/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>
    #
    # TypesConfig points to the file containing the list of mappings from
    # filename extension to MIME-type.
    #
    TypesConfig conf/mime.types

    #
    # AddType allows you to add to or override the MIME configuration
    # file specified in TypesConfig for specific file types.
    #
    #AddType application/x-gzip .tgz
    #
    # AddEncoding allows you to have certain browsers uncompress
    # information on the fly. Note: Not all browsers support this.
    #
    #AddEncoding x-compress .Z
    #AddEncoding x-gzip .gz .tgz
    #
    # If the AddEncoding directives above are commented-out, then you
    # probably should define those extensions to indicate media types:
    #
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz

    #
    # AddHandler allows you to map certain file extensions to "handlers":
    # actions unrelated to filetype. These can be either built into the server
    # or added with the Action directive (see below)
    #
    # To use CGI scripts outside of ScriptAliased directories:
    # (You will also need to add "ExecCGI" to the "Options" directive.)
    #
    #AddHandler cgi-script .cgi

    # For type maps (negotiated resources):
    #AddHandler type-map var

    #
    # Filters allow you to process content before it is sent to the client.
    #
    # To parse .shtml files for server-side includes (SSI):
    # (You will also need to add "Includes" to the "Options" directive.)
    #
    #AddType text/html .shtml
    #AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>

#
# The mod_mime_magic module allows the server to use various hints from the
# contents of the file itself to determine its type.  The MIMEMagicFile
# directive tells the module where the hint definitions are located.
#
#MIMEMagicFile conf/magic

#
# Customizable error responses come in three flavors:
# 1) plain text 2) local redirects 3) external redirects
#
# Some examples:
#ErrorDocument 500 "The server made a boo boo."
#ErrorDocument 404 /missing.html
#ErrorDocument 404 "/cgi-bin/missing_handler.pl"
#ErrorDocument 402 http://www.example.com/subscription_info.html
#

#
# MaxRanges: Maximum number of Ranges in a request before
# returning the entire resource, or one of the special
# values 'default', 'none' or 'unlimited'.
# Default setting is to accept 200 Ranges.
#MaxRanges unlimited

#
# EnableMMAP and EnableSendfile: On systems that support it, 
# memory-mapping or the sendfile syscall may be used to deliver
# files.  This usually improves server performance, but must
# be turned off when serving from networked-mounted 
# filesystems or if support for these functions is otherwise
# broken on your system.
# Defaults: EnableMMAP On, EnableSendfile Off
#
#EnableMMAP off
#EnableSendfile on

# Supplemental configuration
#
# The configuration files in the conf/extra/ directory can be 
# included to add extra features or to modify the default configuration of 
# the server, or you may simply copy their contents here and change as 
# necessary.

# Server-pool management (MPM specific)
#Include conf/extra/httpd-mpm.conf

# Multi-language error messages
#Include conf/extra/httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf

# Fancy directory listings
#Include conf/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf

# Language settings
#Include conf/extra/httpd-languages.conf

# User home directories
#Include conf/extra/httpd-userdir.conf

# Real-time info on requests and configuration
#Include conf/extra/httpd-info.conf

# Virtual hosts
Include "/Users/ferg/Library/Containers/com.bitnami.mampstack/Data/app-5_4_9/apache2/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf"

# Local access to the Apache HTTP Server Manual
#Include conf/extra/httpd-manual.conf

# Distributed authoring and versioning (WebDAV)
#Include conf/extra/httpd-dav.conf

# Various default settings
#Include conf/extra/httpd-default.conf

# Configure mod_proxy_html to understand HTML4/XHTML1
<IfModule proxy_html_module>
Include conf/extra/proxy-html.conf
</IfModule>

# Secure (SSL/TLS) connections
Include "/Users/ferg/Library/Containers/com.bitnami.mampstack/Data/app/apache2/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf"
#
# Note: The following must must be present to support
#       starting without SSL on platforms with no /dev/random equivalent
#       but a statically compiled-in mod_ssl.
#
<IfModule ssl_module>
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>

# Deal with user agents that deliberately violate open standards
#
<IfModule setenvif_module>
BrowserMatch "MSIE 10.0;" bad_DNT
</IfModule>
<IfModule headers_module>
RequestHeader unset DNT env=bad_DNT
</IfModule>


AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .phtml

# Security 
ServerSignature Off
ServerTokens Prod

Include "/Applications/MampStack.app/Contents/Resources/app/apache2/conf/ssi.conf"
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
PHPIniDir /Users/ferg/Library/Containers/com.bitnami.mampstack/Data/app/php/etc

Include "/Applications/MampStack.app/Contents/Resources/app/apache2/conf/fastcgi.conf"
#Include "/Applications/MampStack.app/Contents/Resources/app/frameworks/laravel/conf/laravel.conf"
Include "/Applications/MampStack.app/Contents/Resources/app/apps/phpmyadmin/conf/phpmyadmin.conf"

PidFile /Users/ferg/Library/Containers/com.bitnami.mampstack/Data/app/apache2/logs/httpd.pid

EnableSendfile off

Mutex flock:/Users/ferg/Library/Containers/com.bitnami.mampstack/Data/app/apache2/logs


<IfDefine LOAD_USER_CONFIG_FILES>
     IncludeOptional "/Users/ferg/Library/Containers/com.bitnami.mampstack/Data/shared/apache2/conf/*.conf"
</IfDefine>
```

My httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost lockdown.local:8080>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/ferg/Dropbox/web dev/lockdown/site"
    ServerName lockdown.local    
    ServerAlias www.lockdown.local  
    <Directory "/Users/ferg/Dropbox/web dev/lockdown/site">
        Options All
        Allow from All
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And my hosts file:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0 localhost
127.0.0.1   lockdown.local
```

But when I try to load *lockdown.local* in a broswer I get a 403 Forbidden error. The Apache access logs don't tell me much, just:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Jul/2013:08:51:30 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 211
```

But the errors logs report this:

```
[Fri Jul 05 08:51:30.780380 2013] [core:error] [pid 6084] (1)Operation not permitted: [client 127.0.0.1:49693] AH00132: file permissions deny server access: /Users/ferg/Dropbox/web dev/lockdown/site/index.htm
```

I am assuming it's a permissions problem but I cannot think what else to try. I have tried chmod on the website's folder to 755 and 777. I have chown'ed the folder to daemon user and daemon group as specified in the Apache config.

Ls'ing on the site's folder gives me:

```
drwxr-xr-x  10 daemon  daemon  340  3 Jul 20:34 site
```

Any ideas?

(I have read that you have to give apache access all the way to the root but am unsure how to do this. Surely I cannot "chown -R daemon:daemon" up to the root. Do I have to add the daemon user to the staff group, perhaps? Is that safe? I am pretty new to unix stuff and it seems each file/folder can only belong to one user and one group, and permissions are set on that bases. There's no ACLs. Is that right?)

**Update 1:** I ran `chmod go+x ~` to give execute permissions on my user folder to everyone (as suggested in another answer here) but it hasn't helped.

**Update 2:** I tried to add daemon to the staff group which owns the Users folder tree with `sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a daemon -t user staff`. Still getting a 403.

**Update 3:** I created a symbolic link from the MAMP htdocs folder to the site in my Dropbox folder. Apache follows the link but still gives a 403.

**Update 4:** Changed MAMP's `httpd.conf` to use ferg:staff as user and group. This allowed me to run pages form elsewher ein my Documents folder... but not Dropbox.

**Update 5:** I ran `chmod -R go+r ~` to give read access to my entire users folder. Still getting a 403.

**Update 6:** I renamed "web dev" to "webdev" so there are now no spaces in the file path. It had no effect.

**Update 7:** I moved the `<Directory>` section out of the `<VirtualHost>` section in the vhosts file which apparently sometimes solves 403s. Not for me though.

Comment: Is this the default Apache provided by OSX? If so, what does the [http://127.0.0.1](http://127.0.0.1) say?

Comment: Is your built-in apache running on osx? You can check that in System Preferences->Sharing->Internet sharing. Btw, I'm just guessing here, the things you are writing down are really weird.

Comment: @ Eduárd Moldován - I checked. It is turned off.

Comment: The server is not the built-in one, it's Bitnami MAMP Stack (http://bitnami.com/stack/mamp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the Mac App Store [sandbox restrictions](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxQuickStart/AppSandboxQuickStart.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH2-SW3), the application won't be able to serve files from your Dropbox folder (if you open the Console.app application you will probably see some file-read-data deny errors). I would recommend you to download and install the regular [BitNami MAMP stack](http://bitnami.com/stack/mamp/installer) in your /Applications folder so you can freely configure the DocumentRoot path to point DropBox folder.

Comment: So after all that... it wasn't anything to do with osx permissions or apache or virtual hosts. Thank you for putting this to rest, Beltran. I thought I was going mad.

Comment: Yes, sandbox restrictions are tricky. You would not find any problem with standard BitNami MAMP.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your apache configuration i see `unixd_module` is loaded, so apache is running as user/group daemon/daemon. Maybe the root of your problems is this, because of permissions set in Dropbox directory written within your user's home.

If I'm right, you could avoid this problem changing your apache configuration. Take a look within your `httpd.conf` for these lines:

```
User daemon
Group daemon
```

As told, this is the user/group under which the server will answer requests. Looking at your configuration I read your user is `ferg`. And usually, for Mac users, the default group is `staff`. So change it in the following lines:

```
User ferg
Group staff
```

Now you can restart apache.
Every time apache configuration is changed the server must be restated (or configuration reloaded) in order to be sure new config is correctly loaded.

As counter indication of this approach maybe your apache log files cannot be updated anymore (if they were written under daemon/daemon permissions).
This is not a problem if you don't need them, apache works fine even without logs.
But in case you need, we can avoid this problem changing the ownership accordingly.
Well, executing this shell command:

```
sudo chown -R ferg: /Users/ferg/Library/Containers/com.bitnami.mampstack/Data/app/apache2/logs/
```

**Answering to your questions**

About the user used to run apache, yes it is (quite) safe use your own user. Security mostly depends on which service/webapp you have enabled. But your virtual host in `httpd-vhosts.conf` is listening only on localhost interface (`lockdown.local:8080`), so you are the only one that use it locally. 
On the other hands, please pay attention to apache httpd.conf, your apache is listening on all available interfaces. If really want your apache can be accessible only to you from localhost, you should change it

```
Listen 8080
```

into

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:8080
```

And, may be better change your virtual host configuration from this:

```
<VirtualHost lockdown.local:8080>
```

to this:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
```

Just in case, if in future you change your mind, your virtual host will change listen port accordingly with apache config. 
But there should be more to say about apache httpd hardening and security. As said, in your case, you should be quite sure if your apache is listening only on localhost interface.

Regarding your note 1, if you want give the execute permission to others group, may be you need to propagate the execution permission recursively. Please try with:

```
chmod -R go+x ~
```

But, if you really want give the access to apache, you also need to grant the read permission to everyone.

```
chmod -R go+r ~
```

I also suggest you to avoid spaces into directories, especially when you're dealing with apache config files, may be better change the name of directory `web dev` (and of course, the related apache config)

Regarding the filesystem permission on Mac Os X, in your case, I suggest you take a look at the permission for all the directory in the path.

```
/Users/ferg/Dropbox/web dev/lockdown/site
```

I mean take a look at permission granted at this:

```
/Users
/Users/ferg
/Users/ferg/Dropbox
/Users/ferg/Dropbox/web dev
/Users/ferg/Dropbox/web dev/lockdown
/Users/ferg/Dropbox/web dev/lockdown/site
/Users/ferg/Dropbox/web dev/lockdown/site
```

You can see the permission using the `ls` shell command, for example: `ls -l /Users` 
In order to be sure Apache can access in the `site` directory, you really need all the path have the `execute` permission to the `others` group. And inside the `site` directory all the files have the `read` permission to `others` group.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Unfortunately none of your suggestions worked but I do appreciate you taking the time to answer so have awarded the bounty to you.

Comment: @voidstate I really want understand what's wrong. I have few questions, when you have time, please switch this conversation in chat mode.

Comment: Thanks. I have created a room here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33553/voidstates-mamp-problems

Answer (score 1):

Personally I don't see any issue here.

403 error happens when there is permission issue with the folder or there is no index document. So have you created a test file index.html and put it in "site" folder? Otherwise it's reasonable that you see 403 error.

Another thing I would like to comment is you shouldn't use space for folder name, it will create some headaches sooner or later. So change the folder name "web dev" to something like "webdev" or "web_dev".

Hope this helps ;)